# AngularJS JSONP issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jsonp

I am able to get data with

```
 $http.jsonp("http://url/GetAll?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.eventSource = JSON.stringify(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("ERROR: Could not get data.");
            });
```

I know I can also use a callback method to get data like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://url/GetAll",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',            
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
    });

    myCallback = function (data) {
        alert(data);
        //$scope.eventSource = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
```

Unfortunately I need this as a factory or a service and will be called inside a module. So what I tried is doing this, but it does not work:

```
app.factory('calendarFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    query: function () {            
        var promise = $http.jsonp("http://url/GetAll?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
            success(function (data, status) {

                //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                //myData = JSON.stringify(data);
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("ERROR: Could not get data.");
            });

        return promise;
    }
}
```

});

The console prints the data.. but when I try to add it to a scoped variable, it does not work..

```
 $scope.eventSource = calendarFactory.query();
```

Script references are all good because it works with dummy data. Please don't say a callback method is required. Look at my second script. That has a callback method. I need the third script to work. Something's definitely wrong as I am not getting data in the fourth script.

**More Update:**

I changed the controller to this:

```
 $scope.eventSource = [];
calendarFactory.query().success(function (data) {
        //myVar = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.eventSource = JSON.stringify(data);
});



console.log($scope.eventSource);
```

Now while this is more promising, the problem is the log displays [] first and then the data. This means the factory call is happening very late. Too late for the changes to stick. I tried with a *$scope.$watch('eventSource', function () { same factory call}* but that does not work either.

Now, I am really desperate to get this working. I can consider even a custom JQuery function that can do the trick.

**Some more updates..**
So I now tried using promise..

```
app.service('calendarFactory', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    query: function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: "jsonp", url: URL })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });            
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}
```

});

```
$scope.eventSource = calendarFactory.query();

$scope.eventSource.then(function (items) {
    $scope.eventSource = JSON.stringify(items);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}, function (status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

But it still does not update the page.

Can someone show a working sample of an angular service that makes JSONp request?

Comment: Can you clean up the line right after `query: function() {`?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste mistake. Cleaned up. Still looking for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to deal with JSONP request using $resource.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
app.service('calendarFactory', function ($resource, $q) {
    return {
        query: function () {
            return $resource(URL, {
                get: {
                    method: 'jsonp'
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

function Ctrl($scope, calendarFactory) {
    $scope.eventSource = calendarFactory.query().get();
}
```

Comment: I did that and in the controller added Console.log($scope.eventSource); 

That outputs a resource object. Which seems correct. In the view, I have a div like :  ng-model="eventSources"
It does not render/update as it should with hardcoded array of data.

Comment: What is this: 'TypeError: Cannot read property '__id' of undefined' ?